# Harry Potter “When you could have been celebrating? I must have passed a dozen feasts and parties on my way here.”

Tags: british-english

> He turned to smile at the tabby, but it had gone. Instead he was
> smiling at a rather severe-looking woman who was wearing square
> glasses exactly the shape of the markings the cat had had around its
> eyes. She, too, was wearing a cloak, an emerald one. Her black hair
> was drawn into a tight bun. She looked distinctly ruffled.
> “How did you know it was me?” she asked.
> “My dear Professor, I’ve never seen a cat sit so stiffly.”
> “You’d be stiff if you’d been sitting on a brick wall all day,” said Professor McGonagall.
> **“All day? When you could have been celebrating? I must have passed a dozen feasts and parties on my way here.”**
> Professor McGonagall sniffed angrily.

I am confused about the sentence in bold. My understanding is: Since many people know Voldemort has gone, there must be celebrations. Therefore Dumbledore is surprised that McGonagall just waited here for a whole day rather than join the celebrations.

However I am not sure whether my understanding is correct or not. Could anyone help me please? Thank you very much! ;)

Comment: Your understanding is correct but you missed how it was expressed: You could have been celebrating **instead of sitting on brick all day**.

Comment: Thank you very much Lambie!